# Topology of pointwise convergence - open sets

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Let $X$ be the vector space of all complex functions on $[0,1]$, topologized by the family of seminorms $p_{x}(f)=|f(x)|$, $0\le x\le1$. This topology is called the topology of pointwise convergence.
There is Theorem 1.37 in Rudin's Functional analysis which gives us the base for this topology. Am I right that these sets are $V_n=\{f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{C}\,|\,|f(x)|<\frac{1}{n},x\in J_n\}$, where $J_n$ is a finite subset of $[0,1]$? How can we establish equivalency between convergence in this topology and the standard pointwise convergence? Any help would be highly appreciated.
I am confused about these sets $J_n$. They are finite (because of finite intersections from the theorem), but this is a countable base, so their union cannot be the whole $[0,1]$. I am not understanding something well here...

Theorem 1.37: Suppose $P$ is a separating family of seminorms on a vector space $X$. Associate to each $p\in P$ and to each positive integer $n$ the set $V(p,n)=\{x:p(x)<\frac{1}{n}\}$. Let $B$ be the collection of all finite intersections of the sets $V(p,n)$. Then $B$ is a convex balanced base for a topology $\tau$ on $X$, which turns $X$ into a localy convex space such that every p is continuous...

Comment: Can you include the statement of Theorem 1.37?

Comment: A base of the pointwise topology is $\lbrace V_{J,\varepsilon}: \varepsilon >0,\, J$ finite$\rbrace$ where $V_{J,\varepsilon}= \lbrace f:[0,1]\to \mathbb C: |f(x)|<\varepsilon$ for all $x\in J\rbrace$.

Comment: @Jochen: For all possible choices of finite $J\in[0,1]$?

Comment: In the terminology of Rudin, the sets $V(p_x,n)$ and their finite intersections form a base for a topology. And it is not difficult to see that nets (or sequences) converge in this topology (i.e. are eventually in $V(p_x,n)$ iff the net converges pointwise.